# Fortran program running on Ubuntu 22.04.1 but not on Debian 11

Tags: debian, ubuntu, fortran

I am trying to run a Fortran program distributed as an executable for Linux (HOM4PS2_64-bit.tar.gz on [HOM4PS](http://www.math.nsysu.edu.tw/%7Eleetsung/works/HOM4PS_soft_files/HOM4PS_Linux.htm)).

The program works fine on a machine running Ubuntu 22.04.1 (kernel: 5.19.0-42-generic). However, when trying the program (using test files shipped with the code, such as barry.sym) on a machine running Debian 11 (kernel: 5.10.0-23-amd64) the program fails with the following error:

```
forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source             
flwcrv             0000000000473523  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
flwcrv             00000000004FC730  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
flwcrv             00000000004734FF  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
flwcrv             00000000004FC730  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown

Stack trace terminated abnormally.
```

I am aware that stack overflow could be one reason for the above error message. However, it should not really be a problem in this case, but I have also tried running the program after setting `ulimit -s unlimited` with the same result as above.

What could be the reason(s) the program works on the Ubuntu machine but not the Debian machine? Is there anything I could do to address the issue? Note that I do not have access to the source code.

I also considered posting the question on Stack Overflow instead. Please let me know if you think that would be more appropriate.

Comment: According [forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/forrtl-severe-174-SIGSEGV-segmentation-fault-occurred/m-p/746775) "_there are infinite possibilities_", including [running out of memory](https://suncat.stanford.edu/wiki/common-errors-and-possible-solutions).

Comment: @U880D Thanks for the link! Yes, I have seen that page. I am just a little sursprised that it would work on one system but not on another, fairly closely related system. Also note that I tried running with unlimited stack size, to no avail.